# Dependency Injection - What to do with custom GUI classes?

Tags: user-interface, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Most of the examples, if not all, that I can find (Google + Mark Seemann's Dependency Injection in .NET) on using dependency injection show how to inject service objects.  That is, objects that provide a service.  Ex: an AudioPlayer, a TaxCalculator, a RandomQuoteGenerator, etc, and injecting these types of dependencies seems clear and makes complete sense to me.  What I am not clear on is what to do with GUI objects, since these aren't service objects.

For example, I am working with a GUI framework that requires me to manually code my UI.  I have a MainGui that contains a Toolbar which has several ToolbarButtons on it.  Thus, the hierarchy is something like this:

```
MainGui
    ToolBar
        ToolbarButton
        etc.
```

All these GUI classes are inherited from some base classes.  Are GUI objects candidates for injection?  If yes, how do I deal with a situation where my Toolbar depends on 5 different ToolbarButtons (the only thing differentiating them is their Text property)?

Comment: What benefit would injection provide?

Comment: Robert Harvey, believe it or not, your comment made me think long and hard about an answer, and I've come to a conclusion that I'm satisfied with.  It seems dependency injection works well when using an MVP design pattern for the UI.  In my case, MainGui, ToolBar, and ToolbarButton can all be refactored to implement their own interfaces and to use their own presenter to interact with them.  My DI container can now map these interfaces to a concrete implementation.  To answer you question directly, injection would provide easily swappable views.

Comment: Indeed.  Makes sense to me.